# How to display full file name in lldb

Tags: c++, macos, lldb

I'm pretty familiar with the basic commands of gdb. Unfortunately Apple switched to lldb which has completely different set of commands and now I need to learn a new tool.

Trying to debug a program I step into the function, but it does not display a full file name where the function is. So no path to the file.

Is there a command to retrieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you compile with `-g`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something descriptive of the problem you're having or the question you're asking. *Trying to learn* is a statement or goal, not a problem description or question. Your title should be descriptive enough to be meaningful to a future reader here who finds it in a search result.

Comment: @KenWhite, just did.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `image lookup -n <func-name>` to get the file name

```
(lldb) image lookup -n main
1 match found in /Users/ml9951/manticore/trunk/src/regression-tests/goals/seq-logging/a.out:
    Address: a.out[0x0000000100027670] (a.out.__TEXT.__text + 156144)
    Summary: a.out`main at main.c:90    <<--------
(lldb)
```

It doesn't have the entire path, but hopefully this helps some.

Comment: is it going to display all files where this function is available?

Comment: Adding -v will print more info, including the full path to the file in the "CompileUnit" field.  It will only show where the function is defined, so for a normal function you'll only get one hit.  But if the function is inlined it will show all the places it is inlined into.

Answer (score 2):

```
(lldb) image lookup -v -a $pc
      Address: libjvm.so[0x0000000001a3c2c4] (libjvm.so.PT_LOAD[1]..text + 24588836)
      Summary: libjvm.so`SystemDictionaryShared::add_lambda_proxy_class(InstanceKlass*, InstanceKlass*, Symbol*, Symbol*, Symbol*, Method*, Symbol*, JavaThread*) + 356 at systemDictionaryShared.cpp:1642:3
       Module: file = "/home/foo/bar/jdk17u-git/build/linux-x86_64-server-fastdebug/images/jdk/lib/server/libjvm.so", arch = "x86_64"
  CompileUnit: id = {0x0000038b}, file = "/home/foo/bar/jdk17u-git/src/hotspot/share/classfile/systemDictionaryShared.cpp", language = "c++14"
     Function: id = {0x0d35d4df}, name = "SystemDictionaryShared::add_lambda_proxy_class(InstanceKlass*, InstanceKlass*, Symbol*, Symbol*, Symbol*, Method*, Symbol*, JavaThread*)", mangled = "_ZN22SystemDictionaryShared22add_lambda_proxy_classEP13InstanceKlassS1_P6SymbolS3_S3_P6MethodS3_P10JavaThread", range = [0x00007ffff74ff160-0x00007ffff74ff79d)
     FuncType: id = {0x0d35d4df}, byte-size = 0, decl = systemDictionaryShared.cpp:1631:6, compiler_type = "void (class InstanceKlass *, class InstanceKlass *, class Symbol *, class Symbol *, class Symbol *, class Method *, class Symbol *, class JavaThread *)"
       Blocks: id = {0x0d35d4df}, range = [0x7ffff74ff160-0x7ffff74ff79d)
    LineEntry: [0x00007ffff74ff2c4-0x00007ffff74ff2c9): /home/foo/bar/jdk17u-git/src/hotspot/share/classfile/systemDictionaryShared.cpp:1642:3
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       Symbol: id = {0x000055ba}, range = [0x00007ffff74ff160-0x00007ffff74ff79d), name="SystemDictionaryShared::add_lambda_proxy_class(InstanceKlass*, InstanceKlass*, Symbol*, Symbol*, Symbol*, Method*, Symbol*, JavaThread*)", mangled="_ZN22SystemDictionaryShared22add_lambda_proxy_classEP13InstanceKlassS1_P6SymbolS3_S3_P6MethodS3_P10JavaThread"
     Variable: id = {0x0d35d4fd}, name = "caller_ik", type = "InstanceKlass *", location = DW_OP_reg12 R12, decl = systemDictionaryShared.cpp:1631:68
     Variable: id = {0x0d35d512}, name = "lambda_ik", type = "InstanceKlass *", location = DW_OP_reg3 RBX, decl = systemDictionaryShared.cpp:1632:68
...
```